# Картинка поверх фона двух цветов в email-рассылке

Tags: html, css, вёрстка-email

Верстаю html-письмо и столкнулся с необходимостью сделать картинку в разрезе блоков двух цветов, примерно как расположен аватар на картинке ниже (поверх одновременно серого и синего блока):

[image: Скриншот]

Самым простым решением видится сделать image с двухцветным фоном. Но можно ли это сделать средствами HTML и inline-css, которые будут нормально отображаться в почтовых клиентах?

Comment: Что конкретно вызывает сложность? Используйте табличную верстку для ваших блоков, background-image для изображений, для круглой аватарки div с абсолютным позиционированием, примените к нему border-radius

Comment: Я думал, что div со свойством position будет работать не во всех почтовых клиентах. По-крайней мере, в рекомендоанных свойствах CSS в гайде, которым я пользовался, не было position, а также left, top и т.д.

Comment: Да, действительно position работает только в gmail и mail.ru

Comment: Тут в любой не понятной ситуации лучше делать все изображением, либо париться с таблицами. Где окружность и фоновое изображение лучше сделать это все вместе с помощью img, просто закинуть png с прозрачным фоном

Comment: А разве margin не игнорируется некоторыми почтовыми клиентами?

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, единственный вариант сделать так:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body style = "width:100%;height:100%">
<div style="padding:50px;max-width:600px;background:gray">

<table  border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr >
<td colspan=3 style="width:100%;height:100%;background-image: url(http://archsupport.ru/img/1.png);background-size:100%;background-repeat:no-repeat">
 <p style="text-align:center;padding:25% 5% 19% 5% ">Верстаю html-письмо<br> и столкнулся с необходимостью сделать картинку в разрезе блоков двух цветов, примерно как расположен аватар на картинке ниже (поверх одновременно серого и синего блока)</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height:200px;text-align:center;background:#f3f3f3">
<td style="background:tomato">ANYTHING</td>
<td style="background:coral">ANYTHING</td>
<td style="background:orange">ANYTHING</td>
</tr>
<tr  style="height:200px;text-align:center;background:#f3f3f3">
<td colspan=3 >FOOTER</td>
</tr>
</table>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Не мешало бы ещё кое-что подкрутить, чтобы было более адаптивно, но общий принцип такой.

Позиционирование действительно не работает в большинстве почтовых клиентов,соответственно вы не сможете использовать z-index,или абсолютное позиционирование, поэтому лучше использовать `background-image`.

Это работает везде кроме Outlook, либо просто img, но тогда придется и текст по верх картинки тоже делать в изображении

Comment: Да, сделать фоновым изображением - это путь, который я на данный момент выбрал. Просто подумал, что что-то упускаю, и может как-то проще все возможно было сделать. Там даже фонового изображения не нужно, просто блоки двух цветов, поверх которых блок с картинкой. По структуре, что-то вроде такого: https://jsfiddle.net/fsr5kdhz/15/

Comment: @MikhailKutnyashenko что-то вроде такого не получиться сделать, позиционирование не сработает

Comment: Окей. Спасибо. Заверстал с background-image :)